# return empty in tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get specific tensors using `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations()` and
`tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name()`, but get empty list.

In TensorFlow 1.7.0, with the same code, I can get expected result:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1],name='aa')
print(tf.get_default_graph().get_operations())
print(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('aa:0'))
```

the output is

```
[<tf.Operation 'aa' type=Const>, <tf.Operation 'aa_1' type=Const>]
Tensor("aa:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

However, when I turn to TensorFlow 2.3.0. The result is empty.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1],name='aa')
print(tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations())
print(tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('aa:0')) // will throw error
```

Why? So how to get the tensors in TensorFlow 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can get results by disabling eager execution in `TF 2.x`. Please refer working code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() # disable eager execution

a = tf.constant([1],name='aa')
print(tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations())
print(tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('aa:0'))
```

Output:

```
2.4.1
[<tf.Operation 'aa' type=Const>]
Tensor("aa:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```